# How to use perldoc to find documentation on "@ISA"?

Tags: perl, perldoc

I know this is a silly question. I have been using Perl now for about 2 months, and I'm interested in `perldoc`. I used `man perldoc` to find out how to use it, and tried to find documentation on the `@ISA` variable.

But when I do:

```
$perldoc -v @ISA
```

It says

```
No documentation for perl variable '@ISA' found
```

Am I using the `perldoc` right? Or do I need to install something?

Comment: I would personally strongly suggest going to web docs (google any term preceded with "perldoc"). This gives you MUCH better searchability than perldoc command, and other web based benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`perldoc -v` checks [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), but 
`@ISA` isn't document there, unfortunately.

`@ISA` is documented in [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html). It's checked during method resolution to obtain a list of the class's parent classes.

```
{
   package Base;
   sub new {
      my ($class) = @_;
      my $self = bless({}, $class);
      return $self;
   }

   sub do {
      print("do\n");
   }
}

{
   package Child;
   our @ISA = 'Base';
}

Child->new()->do();  # @ISA is consulted to locate "new" and "do".
```

Comment: you never fail to amuse me @Ikegami. Thanks

Comment: By the way, `perldoc perldoc` documents `perldoc`. `perldoc perlvar` and `perldoc perlobj` brings up the documents I linked.

Comment: lol! I think you mean "amaze", not "amuse". I'm the one who's amused.